# Check if element is clickable in Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to find an element by XPath, and if it is not found then execute the function again. It seems to be getting stuck on the finding element function, and I'm not sure why. I have this working on another site with the same method. Here are my attempts:

Attempt 1:

```
while (url == "https://drygoods.phish.com/dept/posters-prints-and-paper-goods")
try
{
   driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath($"//img[contains(@alt, '{Keyword}')]")).Click();
}
catch
{
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   DryGoodsFindProductKeyword(Keyword, task);
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
if (driver[task].Url != "https://drygoods.phish.com/dept/posters-prints-and-paper-goods")
{
   driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath("//div[2]/div[2]/div/button")).Click();
   driver[task].Url = "https://drygoods.phish.com/cart/";
   //SolveCaptcha(task);
   driver[task].FindElement(By.Id("GoToCheckout")).Click();
   MessageBox.Show("Click Checkout");
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
else
{
   driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath($"//img[contains(@alt, '{Keyword}')]")).Click();
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver[task], TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
   wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlContains("product"));
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   DryGoodsFindProductKeyword(Keyword, task);
```

Here is my full method as well:

```
public void DryGoodsFindProductKeyword(string Keyword, int task)
{
   String url = driver[task].Url;
   driver[task].Url = "https://drygoods.phish.com/dept/posters-prints-and-paper-goods";
   if (driver[task].Url != "https://drygoods.phish.com/dept/posters-prints-and-paper-goods")
   {
   driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath("//div[2]/div[2]/div/button")).Click();

   driver[task].Url = "https://drygoods.phish.com/cart/";
   //SolveCaptcha(task);
   driver[task].FindElement(By.Id("GoToCheckout")).Click();
   MessageBox.Show("Click Checkout");
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
   }
   else
   {
      driver[task].FindElement(By.XPath($"//img[contains(@alt, '{Keyword}')]")).Click();
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver[task], TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
      wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlContains("product"));
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      DryGoodsFindProductKeyword(Keyword, task);
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help! Please let me know if I can add anymore information.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the page is loaded instead of just your URL changing you can use

```
wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```

Maybe your element isn't displayed yet or it isn't enabled. They're both properties on your IWebElement. You could use this to see if it's clickable:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(byLocatorGoesHere)).Click();
```

If it's slightly out of view you may need to use Javascript to click it (or just scroll it into view).